# Prove the set is closed with respect to its norm......

Tags: functional-analysis, inequality, convergence-divergence, normed-spaces

Let $V$ be a normed vector space over **R**.

Let $W$ be a proper closed subspace of $V$.

We say $w^*$ is a best approximation in $W$ to $v^* \in V$

if $\|v^*-w^*\| \leq \|v^*-w\|$ for all $w \in W$.

For a give $v^* \in V$, let $M$ be its set of best approximations in $W$.

Prove that $M$ is closed convex.

---

I proved that $M$ is convex.

But I'm having hard time proving that $M$ is closed with respect to the norm.

The following is my attempt to prove $M$ is closed with respect to its norm.

---

$$M = \{w ' \in W : \|v^*-w'\| \leq \|v^*-w\| \text{ for all }w \in W\}$$

Let {$w_n$} be a convergent sequence in $M$ converging to $w_o \in W$

So for all $\epsilon > 0 $, there exists $N$ such that for $n > N$,

we have $\|w_n - w_o\| < \epsilon$

Then we want to show that $w_o \in M$

That is, we want to show that $\|v^* - w_o\| \leq \|v^* - w\|$ for all $w \in W$.

---

I've been playing with triangular inequality.

But it doesn't work so far.

Can you help me with this?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Fix $w\in W$.  We have for each n,  $\|v^*-w_n\|\le \|v^*-w\|$  Now, take the limit as $n\to \infty$, and use the fact that the norm is continuous to justify exchanging the limit with the norm, to conclude that $\|v^*-w_0\|\le \|v^*-w\|$